# Controlling height of multi-line QLabel in QScrollArea in QGridLayout for pyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5

I want a widget, which will be a horizontally scrollable text label, placed in the middle of a window (which is otherwise laid out via QGridLayout). With the code example below, I get this:

[image: pyqt5-Tester.png]

The image shows, that the label itself, allocated vertical space which is just enough for the two lines - which is what I want.

However, there is also extra vertical space, from the end (the bottom) of the label, to the start (the top) of the scrollbar.

Can I somehow get rid of this extra space, so the label keeps its current height, while it "sticks" to the scrollbar - and while still keeping the QGridLayout?

The code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    self.layout = QGridLayout()

    self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 20)
    self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 0)
    self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 20)

    self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

    self.mylbl = QLabel("[]\n[]", self)
    self.mylbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
    self.mylbl.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: gray;}")
    self.mylbl.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
    self.mylbl.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

    self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.mylbl)
    self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn )

    self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, *(1,0), *(1,2))

    self.setLayout(self.layout)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 220, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the label will always have the same height, you can set a fixed height to the scrollarea:

```
    # get the size hint of the label
    height = self.mylbl.sizeHint().height()
    # add the scrollbar height
    height += self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()
    # add the scrollarea frame size * 2 (top and bottom)
    height += self.scrollArea.frameWidth() * 2

    self.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(height)
```

Comment: Thanks @musicamante - that works great (apart from the typo in `self.self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()`, which should be `self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()`)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for noticing the typo!